# Databricks: Spark Structured Stream from Kafka stuck at "Stream initialising"

Tags: python, apache-spark, streaming, databricks

I want to create a structured stream in databricks with a kafka source.
I followed the instructions as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). My script seems to start, however I am unable to print/output something in the databricks notebook. The stream itsellf works fine and produces results and works (in databricks) when I use `confluent_kafka`, thus there seems to be a different issue I am missing:

The script seems "stuck" at "Running Command" / "Stream Initialising".

Any input is highly appreciated!

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Define a data schema
schema = StructType() \
           .add('PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_070_VALUES', StringType())\
           .add('ID', StringType())\
           .add('PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_001_VALUES', StringType())\
           .add('TIMESTAMP', TimestampType())


df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("host", "stream.xxx.com") \
    .option("port", 12345)\
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'stream.xxx.com:12345') \
    .option('subscribe', 'stream_test.json') \
    .option("startingOffset", "earliest") \
    .load()

df_word = df.select(F.col('key').cast('string'),
                    F.from_json(F.col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("parsed_value"))
  
# Group by id and count
df_group = df_word.select('parsed_value.*')\
                  .groupBy('ID').count()

query = df_group \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

my stream output data looks like this:

```
"PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_070_VALUES":'something'
"ID":"47575963333908"
"PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_001_VALUES":12345
"TIMESTAMP": "2020-10-22T15:06:42.507+02:00"
```

To clarify: I am trying to print the components of `query` to the notebook to test the connection. There is no cell following this or previous to the above cell.

Thanks and stay safe.

Comment: BTW: I know my question has non-reproducible code, however in this scenario I feel unable to produce that :/

Comment: Are you trying to print out something in the notebook after this cell?  If so, remove query.awaitTermination()

Comment: hi @JoeWiden - i am trying to print the output of `query` to the notebook.

Comment: I'm trying to do that in this cell, there is nothing following this cell and I removed `query.awaitTermination()`, which changed nothing.

Comment: id you do display(df_group) andget rid of the query =, does that accomplish what you want?

Comment: This also gets the notebook stuck at „stream initialising“

Comment: @heck1 , I know this is old but I am having exact same issue.. did you find a solution?

Comment: @PKT cheers, unfortunately, it turned out that the reason it was not initializing had to do with the stream being structured in partitions and the consumer did not account for that. If you are using Azure, i can reccomend checking out Stream Analystics Jobs, those were really helpful in my case.

Comment: Hey, Can you provide what you did to resolve, Im also facing the same issue while writing it to Delta it's stuck at Initializing ,Im reading from EventHub and working on Azure

Comment: Cheers, so we used an Event Hub to make some easy queries and then stored into a small db, which would empty every hour, since the data was only necessary for a dashboard.

Comment: to use the mirrormaker, we stepped away from Databricks and worked with the following: https://github.com/djrosanova/EventHubsMirrorMaker

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the deprecated Kafka offset reader, when an invalid  config (e.g. wrong ip address or port) is passed in. This is due to an issue with the Kafka client when fetching metadata.

A new offset reader was enabled by default which will throw Kafka `TimeoutException` in such situation. If you are using an older version, set spark config:

***spark.sql.streaming.kafka.useDeprecatedOffsetFetching*** to ***false***

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#offset-fetching